# MapStruct - weld injection for second mapper not working

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, inject, mapstruct

I have a problem with injection in weld cdi for mappers using mapstruct library.
When I have only one mapper everything is working.
After adding second mapper this mapper throws exception:
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type InspectionTypeMapper with qualifiers @Default

First mapper(this mapper works)

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "cdi", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public interface InstallationMapper {
    Installation installationDtoToInstallation(InstallationDto installationDto);
    InstallationDto installationToInstallationDto(Installation installation);
    List<InstallationDto> installationsToInstallationsDtos(List<Installation> installations);

}
```

Second mapper(this is not working and throw exception):

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "cdi", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public interface InspectionTypeMapper {
    InspectionType inspectionTypeDtoToInspectionType(InspectionTypeDto inspectionTypeDto);
    InspectionTypeDto inspectionTypeToInspectionTypeDto(InspectionType inspectionType);
    List<InspectionTypeDto> inspectionTypesToInspectionTypeDtos(List<InspectionType> inspectionTypes);
}
```

My installationServiceImpl:

```
@RequestScoped
public class InstallationServiceImpl implements InstallationService {
@Inject
private InstallationRepository installationRepository;
@Inject
private InstallationMapper installationMapper;

@Override
public List<InstallationDto> getAllInstallations() {
    List<Installation> installations = installationRepository.getAll();
    List<InstallationDto> installationDtos = installationMapper.installationsToInstallationsDtos(installations);
    return installationDtos;
    }
}
```

My InspectionTypeServiceImpl:

```
@RequestScoped
public class InspectionTypeServiceImpl implements InspectionTypeService{
@Inject
InspectionTypeRepository inspectionTypeRepository;

@Inject
InspectionTypeMapper inspectionTypeMapper;
@Override
public List<InspectionTypeDto> getAllInspectionTypes() {
    List<InspectionType> inspectionTypes = inspectionTypeRepository.getAll();
    System.out.println(inspectionTypes);
    List<InspectionTypeDto> inspectionTypeDtos = inspectionTypeMapper
            .inspectionTypesToInspectionTypeDtos(inspectionTypes);
    return inspectionTypeDtos;
}
```

Comment: are you sure an implementation is actually generated during the build for the `InspectionTypeMapper`? Check the deployable (ear/war/jar) if there's indeed an `InspectionTypeMapperImpl`..

Comment: yes it is, in /generated folder, but it has ApplicationScoped, and I inject first and second mapper in my Measurement bean which is ViewScoped, could it be a reason?

Comment: I'm not an expert on CDI.. But you could try without a mapper. Its just code, albeit generated. Don't think its a MapStruct issue.. Did  you try constructor injection by the way?

Comment: In what environment are you running? Do you start Weld (CDI) yourself or is it some EE server doing it for you? If both impls are generated and in the same folder and one is "found by Weld" and the other isn't, then there is a question on how you discover those beans (files in this case)? That might boil down to either how you start Weld or how does MapStruct register their beans with CDI - they could be using extensions but I doubt it since they just generate full blown class as beans.

Comment: I'm running this on WebSphere. I'm not starting weld, server doing this.
I resolved this by simple server restart.